# No routes matches, for named route in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have problem with rails routing.

Error is:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"orders", :action=>"sell_item"}
```

Route rule looks like:

```
match 'orders/sell/:id' => 'orders#sell_item', as: 'sell_item'
```

link generation in the view file:

```
<%= link_to 'sell', sell_item_url, id: line_item.id %>
```

function in the OrdersController

```
def sell_item(line_item_id)
  line_item = LineItem.find(line_item_id)
  line_item.status = 1
  line_item.save
end
```

It still generates route if I remove '/:id' from route and ',id: line_item.id' from link_to.

Comment: Id option in link_to generates <a id=`value`></a>... so pass value to url helper as parameter

Comment: got it. I'm pretty new in Ruby and Rails, so not all things are clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<%= link_to 'sell', sell_item_url, id: line_item.id %>
```

try

```
<%= link_to 'sell', sell_item_url(line_item) %>
```

Rails should build the route for you based on the object.

See here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects